# Applying np.dot to each row of two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have two Pandas DataFrames of equal shape and I'd like to produce a Series which is the row-wise (thinking of using pandas.DataFrame.apply) dot product of the two DataFrames.

So, for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,10))
df1.apply(np.dot, axis=1, args=[df2.ix[???]]
```

Is there a compact, vectorized way to do this without concatenating into one DataFrame and defining some custom function?  I believe that this is difficult since I cannot implicitly index the row from `df2` that corresponds to the same index from `df1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could multiply the two DataFrames together, and then sum along `axis=1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,10))
result = (df1*df2).sum(axis=1)
```

Note that when you multiply two DataFrames together, Pandas aligns the rows based on the index. This takes time. If the values are already aligned, then you could drop down to NumPy and use

```
result = (df1.values * df2.values).sum(axis=1)
```

or

```
result = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', df1.values, df2.values)
```

This is quicker since there is no need to align rows based on indices first.

```
In [10]: %timeit (df1*df2).sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 379 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit (df1.values * df2.values).sum(axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.8 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->i', df1.values, df2.values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30 µs per loop
```

`(df1.values * df2.values).sum(axis=1)` returns a 1D NumPy array. To make a Series with the same index as `df1` you would use

```
pd.Series(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', df1.values, df2.values), index=df1.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like unutbu's answer.  Another I've come up with, between two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
dot_prods = np.dot(df1, df2.transpose()).diagonal()
```

If the column names in `df1` are different than in `df2`, a quick workaround, using `.values` like unutbu:

```
dot_prods = np.dot(df1.values, df2.transpose().values).diagonal()
```

A variation on these that doesn't need a numpy import:

```
dot_prods = df1.values.dot(df2.values.transpose()).diagonal()
```

I like this way because it keeps keeps the 'dot' function in the code (I try to make the intention of my code clear), and it is vectorized and drawing on pandas/numpy native functionality, but unutbu's way is more succinct.  Good luck!

**EDIT**

Also looks like the method I gave performed a little faster:

```
In [73]: %timeit df1.values.dot(df1.values.transpose()).diagonal()
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.7 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit (df1.values * df1.values).sum(axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.3 µs per loop
```